# How to launch a clojure repl with access to a jar

Tags: clojure, leiningen

I'm new to clojure. I have a jar file I want to play with in a clojure repl, but I've failed to do so with leiningen 2.

I have tried placing the jar file in src/myjar.jar and also in src/org/mydomain/myjar.jar

When I run lein repl I get errors stating that leiningen can not find my artifact, and a reference to a page about repeatability which I do not understand.

Here is my project.clj (with the real name of myjar)

```
(defproject cljliveordead "0.1.0-SNAPSHOT"
  :description "FIXME: write description"
  :url "http://example.com/FIXME"
  :license {:name "Eclipse Public License"
            :url "http://www.eclipse.org/legal/epl-v10.html"}
  :dependencies [[org.clojure/clojure "1.3.0"]
                 [org.allen.temporalintervalrelationships/time "0.2" :extension "jar"]])
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use local jars using the lein-localrepo plugin.  Add this line to your project.clj

```
:plugins [[lein-localrepo "0.4.0"]]
```

Then install the jar to the local repository using

```
lein localrepo install <path-to-jar> org.allen.temporalintervalrelationships/time 0.2
```

You can check that the file is installed by running `lein localrepo list` and check that lein can resolve the project dependencies using `lein deps`.  If all is well then you can start playing with the jar using `lein repl`.

Leiningen doesn't like local jars due to its goal of [repeatable builds](https://github.com/technomancy/leiningen/wiki/Repeatability).  If this was a real project using a third party closed source jar then the best thing to do is install it in a local Nexus repository and add a reference to that repository to your project.

However, this all seems a bit heavyweight for what you are trying to achieve.  If all you want to do is play with the jar in the REPL then create a simple project like this

```
(defproject clojure-time "0.1.0-SNAPSHOT"
  :dependencies [[org.clojure/clojure "1.4.0"]
                 [com.cemerick/pomegranate "0.0.13"]])
```

and use the [pomegranate](https://github.com/cemerick/pomegranate) library to add the jar to your classpath manually

```
(require '[cemerick.pomegranate :as p])
(p/add-classpath "jsr-310-ri-0.6.3.jar")
(javax.time.Instant/now)
```

and play away.

Answer (score 1):

the hackish way is to just put it into `/proiject/path/lib/` and the 'proper' way is to:

- add a dependency for it to your project
- run lein deps which will print the command for installing the jar to your local maven repo
- run the command leiningen gives you with the path to your jar
- run lein deps again

Comment: can you clarify the add a dependency step? I have tried to do that in my project.clj but no luck

Comment: what kind of path is /project/path/lib, an absolute one?

Comment: it's my attempt to describe the lib subdirectory under the main project directory. in the same directory as your project.clj their should be a subdir called lib

Comment: Thanks for the help. I placed the jar in lib/org/allen/temporalintervalrelationships/allentemporalintervalrelationshipsv02.jar, but lein repl still gives the same error message. I also tried placing it in the lib directory.

Answer (score 1):

I use clojure-csv in a lot of my applications, so make sure the modules referencing clojure-csv were able to build with it, this is what I did:

0) Ran `lein new bene-csv`

1) Added this to project.clj (after enter lein new bene-csv). The pertinent line is `[clojure-csv/clojure-csv "1.3.2"]`, but it makes sense to show you the whole project.clj for good example's sake.

```
(defproject bene-csv "1.0.4-SNAPSHOT"
  :description "A csv parsing library"
  :dependencies [[org.clojure/clojure "1.3.0"]
                 [clojure-csv/clojure-csv "1.3.2"]
                 [util "1.0.2-SNAPSHOT"]]


  :aot [bene-csv.core]
  :omit-source true)
```

2) Made sure my bene-csv/src/bene_csv/core.clj references clojure-csv.

```
(ns bene-csv.core
  ^{:author "Charles M. Norton",
    :doc "bene-csv is a small library to parse a .csv file.
        Created on March 8, 2012"}
  (:require [clojure.string :as cstr])
  (:require [util.core :as utl])
  (:use clojure-csv.core))
```

Finally, I ran these commands, so that my main project could reference bene-csv's functions and defs.

```
lein deps
lein install
```

Comment: thanks for the help. I'm not sure how this applies to my case because I'm trying to use a raw java jar from lein repl rather than importing a clojure lib.

Comment: My answer tended to go in the direction of using lien based on what you asked. I believe that raw jar file could be imported the same way, by having it on the classpath.